# Run a bash command and split the output by line not by space

Tags: bash

I want to run the following command and get the output in the variable splited in an array by line not by space:

`files=$( hdfs dfs -ls -R $hdfsDir)`

So the output I get is the following: `echo $files`

```
drwxr-xr-x - pepeuser supergroup 0 2016-05-27 15:03 /user/some/kpi/2015/01/02 -rw-r--r-- 3 pepeuser supergroup 55107934 2016-05-27 15:02 /user/some/kpi/2015/01/02/part-00000902148 -rw-r--r-- 3 pepeuser supergroup 49225279 2016-05-27 15:02 /user/some/kpi/2015/01/02/part-00001902148
```

When I do a `for` in $files in stead of getting the full line on each., I get the column in stead of the line. It prints like the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x
-
pepeuser
supergroup
```

and what I need on the `for` to print like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x - pepeuser supergroup 0 2016-05-27 15:03 /user/some/kpi/2015/01/02 
-rw-r--r-- 3 pepeuser supergroup 55107934 2016-05-27 15:02 /user/some/kpi/2015/01/02/part-00000902148 
-rw-r--r-- 3 pepeuser supergroup 49225279 2016-05-27 15:02 /user/some/kpi/2015/01/02/part-00001902148
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have bash 4, you can use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t files < <(hdfs dfs -ls -R "$hdfsDir")
```

Otherwise, use `read -a` to read into an array. `IFS=$'\n'` sets the field separator to newlines and `-d ''` tells it to keep reading until it hits a NUL character: effectively, that means it'll read to EOF.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a files < <(hdfs dfs -ls -R "$hdfsDir")
```

You can verify that the array is populated correctly with something like:

```
printf '[%s]\n' "${files[@]}"
```

And can loop over the array with:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: thanks it works!!! but why the `"${files[@]}"` in the `for` cannot be written just like 
 `$files`?

Comment: @elranu because `$files` equals to `"${files[0]}"` = first array element.

Comment: Also unquoted `for file in $files` would iterate over the (whitespace-separated) **words** of `"${files[0]}"`